# Developing in Visual Studio 2005 for Windows Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to install an ASP.net website developed with Visual Studio 2005 in a server with Windows Server 2012?  Our client is planning to upgrade the server from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012.  Will the application (already developed with VS 2005) run in a 64 bits operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Two things to make sure you do is to have the correct .Net version installed on the windows server and when you setup the new site in IIS (assuming IIS) that the application pool is set to allow 32-bit applications.

This will take you through how to enable 32-bit app pools (it is for IIS7 but IIS 8 is the same)
https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Visual Studio is just a development environment and is intendant of the target server type/version. You can use Visual Studio to develop any .Net application/website no matter where you want to run it. It is all about the server being configured to run a 32-bit .Net application.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I wanted to know.

Comment: There is no need to force 32-bit as VS 2005 already supports true 64-bit development.

Comment: @LexLi True, but it sounds like this is an existing application built way back and is probably configured as a 32-bit app (assumption made from asking of the app will run in a 64-bit OS). The user could recompile into 64-bit and re-run all testing but converting the app is more work then just enabling 32-bit apps in the app pool.